# SQL Combine 3 Statements; Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have 3 statements that i want to combine into one; Just so i can learn is there anyway of doing it?

Insert

```
INSERT INTO plants (name, latin_name, type, stock, price, flower_colour, foilage_colour, features, sun_exposure, soil_type, hardiness, competance, height, spread, description, flowering_season)
VALUES
(dandelion, `Taraxacum officinale`, weed, 12, 1.99, white, green, flower, `full sun`, alkaline, `annual hardy`, low, 12cm, 7cm, d, summer)
```

Update

```
UPDATE plants SET flower_colour='white', soil_type='clay', height='15cm', spread='4cm', description='Weed' AND price='£1.99'
```

Delete

```
DELETE FROM plants WHERE name='dandelion' AND type='weed'
```

Comment: Which RDBMS aye you using?

Comment: Make a stored procedure. Not sure if you consider this "combined" or not but the end result is one call to execute all 3 statements. I don't know of a way to do it otherwise

Comment: phpMyAdmin and if i can run it in one SQL query it will work, If it is possible; how?

Comment: This will be different depending on your RDBMS, some have `MERGE`, some don't

Comment: @DannyHickerz Hamlet was asking for the database engine you are using. MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, etc

Comment: Sorry, it's MySQL. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for you RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if it was possible or not. I don't know an awful lot of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The first question I would ask is "Why would you want to do this"? Given your example, you insert, change and then delete an entry. Unless there's hidden logic such as triggers updating other elements of the data, the state of the data layer won't change as a result of these three commands executing.

Also, your UPDATE statement is not syntactically correct; `AND` can only be used in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause, so I think there's something you mistakenly omitted there.

There really isn't any way to combine inserting, updating and deleting into one single command. You can usually send all three commands as one "script" from whatever code layer you are using, or encapsulate these SQL commands into a stored procedure and execute that, but each statement does something very different to the underlying data, which is why they're different commands to begin with.

Comment: There is on some RDBMS, `MERGE` on SQL Server for example

Comment: The MERGE command's purpose is to change the data of one table based on the data of another query, such as for synchronization. While it may work in the OP's actual situation, it really doesn't do what he's asking for in the question, which is to insert/update/delete based on static query parameters in one go. Of course, what the OP is actually asking for is more than a little nonsensical as my answer mentions.

Comment: You are right, didn't actually read the details of the statements, just the `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` part. Though `MERGE` can still be used somehow